# Trigonometry Circle representation using Python and Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wrote this code using Python 3.5 and Pygame to help me learn more about sine waves. Its goal is to show the variations in the sine and cosine values in the Trigonometry Circle as the distance covered by a point in the circumference increases.

I'd appreciate suggestions and advices about the code, specially about the math involved and my usage of Pygame.

Thanks.

```
import pygame
import math

SCR_WIDTH = 220
SCR_HEIGHT = 480

RAD_SIZE = 100
CIRCLE_X = int(105)
CIRCLE_Y = int(285)

STD_FONT_SZ = 25


def drawChart(frequency, time, turns, sin, cos, surface):
    """Draws the frequency, time, distance, and sine and cosine values on the given surface"""

    freq_txt = font.render("Frequency: {:.3}Hz".format(frequency), False, (0,0,0))
    time_txt = font.render("Time: {:.3}s".format(time), False, (0,0,0))
    turn_txt = font.render("Turns: {:.3}".format(turns), False, (0,0,0))
    sin_txt = font.render("Sine: {:.3}".format(sin), False, (0,0,0))
    cos_txt = font.render("Cosine: {:.3}".format(cos), False, (0,0,0))

    surface.blit(time_txt,(0,0))
    surface.blit(freq_txt,(0,STD_FONT_SZ))
    surface.blit(sin_txt,(0,STD_FONT_SZ*2))
    surface.blit(cos_txt,(0,STD_FONT_SZ*3))
    surface.blit(turn_txt,(0,STD_FONT_SZ*4))



def drawCircle(x,y, surface):
    """Draws the Trigonometry circle on the given surface in position x, y"""

    pygame.draw.line(surface,(0,0,0),(x-RAD_SIZE,y),(x+RAD_SIZE,y))  #x-axis  
    pygame.draw.line(surface,(0,0,0),(x,y-RAD_SIZE),(x,y+RAD_SIZE))  #y-axis
    pygame.draw.circle(surface,(0,0,0), (x,y), RAD_SIZE, 1) #main circle
    surface.blit(x_txt,(x+RAD_SIZE, y)) #x character
    surface.blit(y_txt,(x,y-RAD_SIZE-STD_FONT_SZ-4)) #y character

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("SineRep v. 1.0")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT), 0, 32)
font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",STD_FONT_SZ)

frequency = 0.1

x_txt = font.render("x", False, (0,0,0))
y_txt = font.render("y", False, (0,0,0))

while True:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
    distance = 2*math.pi*time*frequency
    turns = time*frequency    
    cos = math.cos(distance)
    sin = math.sin(distance)

    #size of cosine and sine in pixels
    cos_pxl = int(cos*RAD_SIZE)
    sin_pxl = int(-sin*RAD_SIZE)


    ##### Draw stuff in the screen
    drawChart(frequency, time, turns, sin, cos, screen)
    drawCircle(CIRCLE_X, CIRCLE_Y, screen)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,0,0), (CIRCLE_X+cos_pxl,CIRCLE_Y+sin_pxl), 5, 0) #dot

    #Auxiliary shapes
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,0,0), (CIRCLE_X+cos_pxl,CIRCLE_Y), 3, 1) #cosine dot  
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,0,0), (CIRCLE_X,CIRCLE_Y+sin_pxl), 3, 1) #sine dot    

    pygame.draw.line(screen,(255,0,0),(CIRCLE_X,CIRCLE_Y),(CIRCLE_X+cos_pxl,CIRCLE_Y), 2)  #projection in x (cos)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,(255,0,0),(CIRCLE_X,CIRCLE_Y),(CIRCLE_X,CIRCLE_Y+sin_pxl),2) #projection in y (sine)


    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        break

    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A few remarks**

> ```
> CIRCLE_X = int(105)
> CIRCLE_Y = int(285)
> ```

- Python is a duck typed language, you don't need a type in order to invoke a method or variable. You could omit the `int()` call here

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
> ```

- [guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), use them!

> ```
> pygame.init()
> pygame.display.set_caption("SineRep v. 1.0")
> screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT), 0, 32)
> font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",STD_FONT_SZ)
> frequency = 0.1
> x_txt = font.render("x", False, (0,0,0))
> y_txt = font.render("y", False, (0,0,0))
> ```

- These should not be global, maybe a function? `def setup_game()`

---

- You have a few [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations. A good style creates more readable code :)